# mvnw clean install failed

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I run `sudo ./mvnw clean install`

with this `settings.xml`

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
  <offline>false</offline>
</settings>
```

and i have `mvnw` file like that: https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/master/mvnw

the output is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project X: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project Y:Z:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies at com.octo.captcha:jcaptcha:jar:1.0 -> com.jhlabs:imaging:jar:01012005:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.jhlabs:imaging:jar:01012005: Could not transfer artifact com.jhlabs:imaging:pom:01012005 from/to 3rd-party 
(http://forge.octo.com/archiva/repository/3rd-party): forge.octo.com: Name or service not known: Unknown host forge.octo.com: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
```

But locally in `~/.m2/repository/...` i pasted those files.

from here: http://community.andowson.com/posts/list/152.page;jsessionid=A553230912F5143A61A1696968AC3AAD.worker1#p3